# Segmentation fault on Memory Access

Tags: c, mmap

I have mmapped a base address of `0x40000000` to a virtual memory address. But when I try to read the value of register on the location of `0x40100000`, I get a segmentation fault. The page size used in the `mmap()` function is `4K` where the file descriptor has a value of `3`.

The `init()` function is called from the main to initialize the memory:
Here `UWord8` is `unsigned char` and `UWord32` is `unsigned int`.

```
UWord8 init()
{
    UWord8 error;
    printf("Initializing Devices in Zynq...\n\r\n\r");
    error = initMemory();

    if(error)
    {
        printf("PL:\tAccess Denied\n\r");
        return 1;
    }

    if(!error)
    {
        error = initFpga();
        if(error)
        {
            printf("Access Denied to mmap...\n\r");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

UWord8 initMemory(void)
{
    UWord8 error = 0;

    //Initializing /dev/mem
    fd = open(MEMORY_ACCESS, READ_WRITE);

    if(fd < 1)
    {
        error = 1;
        #if DEBUG_MODE
            printf("Could not open /dev/mem for access\n");
        #endif
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Value of fd is %u\n", fd);
        page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
        printf("The page size is %u\n", page_size);
        #if DEBUG_MODE
            printf("Successfully opened /dev/mem for access\n");
        #endif
    }

    //Opening text file for writing pointer data
    fp = fopen("/home/pointer_data.txt", "a");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        error = 1;
        #if DEBUG_MODE
            printf("Could not open text file for writing.\n\r");
        #endif
    }
    else
    {
        #if DEBUG_MODE
            printf("Successfully opened text file for writing.\n\r");
        #endif
    }
    return error;
}

UWord8 initFpga(void)
{
    UWord8 error = 0;
    unsigned page_addr, device_addr;

    device_addr = BASE_ADDRESS;
    page_addr = (device_addr & (~(page_size-1)));
    fpga_pageOffset = device_addr - page_addr;
    fpga_ptr = mmap(NULL, page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, page_addr); //mmap the device into memory

    if(fpga_ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory mapping to Base address 0x%08x failed...\n\r",BASE_ADDRESS);
        error = 1;
    }   
    return error;
}
```

The following is the function is read the value at a particular address, the address being sent to the function is the offset from base address:

```
UWord32 _getWord(UWord32 address)
{
    UWord32 data = *((unsigned *)(fpga_ptr + fpga_pageOffset + address));
    printf("peek 0x%08x =0x%08x\n\r", BASE_ADDRESS + address, data);
    return data;
}
```

There is no error on this line:

```
_getWord(0x000ffff8)
```

But I get a segmentation fault on:

```
_getWord(0x00100000)
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: I have updated my question now.

Comment: I feel like I'm overlooking something here. You map a 4kb region of memory (page aligned), which corresponds to 0x1000, yet you're trying to access an address 0x100000 bytes beyond the beginning of the map?

Comment: Also, you wouldn't be able to access 0x100000 even if the math worked out exactly, for the same reason that if you malloc space for an array of length 10, you can't access array[10].

Comment: The page size is being calculated using sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), do I just enter a big number, say 64mb and it will work?

Comment: [`mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) returns `MAP_FAILED` on failure, not `NULL`.

Comment: @KulaDamian you may choose any number you wish, but its usually best to "only take what you need". I tend to make my mappings multiple of page sizes as well, but that is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AndrewHenle, i will change that in my code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle And its not just semantics either, `MAP_FAILED` holds the value `(void *) -1`, whereas `NULL` is `(void *) 0`, so you *will* miss the error if you interchange the two.

Comment: Changing the page size helped @DillonDavis. Thanks for helping!!

Comment: @KulaDamian I'll add it as an answer then, so others will see this question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your memory map, you give it a size equal to your pagesize- 4kb.

```
fpga_ptr = mmap(NULL, page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, page_addr); //mmap the device into memory
```

This translates to `0x1000` bytes, however you attempt to access data `0x100000` bytes after the beginning of your map, which raises the segmentation fault. To fix this issue, map a larger region of memory. For example:

```
fpga_ptr = mmap(NULL, 0x1000 * page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, page_addr);
```

This will allow you to access the next `0x1000000` bytes after the beginning of your memory map.